# why the lower.tail=F is used when mannualy calculating the p value from t score

Tags: r, t-test

I was searching on this forum to calculate the p value from a t.test score. 
So I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/manually-calculating-p-value-from-t-value-in-t-test) topic. 
The answer giving:

```
> 2*pt(ttestscore, lower=FALSE)
```

However it makes no sense to me using the lower = FALSE.
[image]

When using the lower = F argument you will calculate the probability of the black shaded area in the second figure right?

This means that you are calculating the probability that the t score is LESS then the giving t score, but you want to calculate the probability that the T score is bigger (if you are giving  the t score as a positive number)?

Comment: The argument is `lower.tail` and if set to `FALSE` the function gives the upper tail probability just as you'd expect and as the documentation says.  Type `?pt` in the R console.

Comment: You may find vonjd's answer in that thread relevant. In particular consider these two (equivalent) alternative versions, the first being his code: 1:... `p.value = 2*pt(-abs(t.value), df=length(data)-1)` ... $\qquad\quad\:\:$ 2: ... `p.value = 2*pt(abs(t.value), df=length(data)-1,lower.tail=FALSE)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the documentation for R's `pt()` function.

> lower.tail
>   logical; if `TRUE` (default), probabilities are P[X ≤ x], otherwise, P[X > x].*

In other words, when lower.tail=FALSE you get the probability to the right of X (the first of your two diagrams).

Or just run it for yourself:

```
> pt(2,10)  
[1] 0.963306  
> pt(2,10,lower.tail = FALSE)  
[1] 0.03669402
```

Answer (score 0):

Student t distribution is symmetric. So if you calculate the area under upper tail and multiply it by 2, you end up with the 2 tailed p-value of your test score.