# lsmeans R package: how to obtain exact pvalue question when doing a pairwise comparision

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, lsmeans

I'm using the `lsmeans` R package, and I'm doing a simple pairwise comparison between two groups. Is there a way to get the exact `p.value` in scientific notation rather than the estimate? I've tried setting options(scipen=100000000000), without luck. It just shows 0.000000e+00 when I do so.

`lsmeans(fit,pairwise~type+age,at=list(age=c("40","50","60")),adjust="mvt")`

```
$contrasts
 contrast     estimate          SE    df  t.ratio p.value
 1 - 2    -0.084728198 0.002606520 59346  -32.506  <.0001
 1 - 3    -0.269773787 0.002146597 59346 -125.675  <.0001
 1 - 4    -0.002048158 0.001896132 59346   -1.080  0.6824
 2 - 3    -0.185045589 0.002406580 59346  -76.892  <.0001
 2 - 4     0.082680040 0.002211575 59346   37.385  <.0001
 3 - 4     0.267725629 0.001064637 59346  251.471  <.0001
```

Comment: `pt(-32.506, 59346)` =  4.61944e-230

Comment: @kmm lol how did you do that?

Comment: @kmm Thanks!!    2*pt(-abs(t),df=n-1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45153/manually-calculating-p-value-from-t-value-in-t-test

Comment: Above will produce UNADJUSTED P values, not the mvt-adjusted ones.

Comment: Looking at this a second time, I don't believe the output shown could have come from that `lsmeans` call, because there are two factors involved. I think you did not have `age` on the rhs of the formula.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by exact? The `"mvt"` method uses simulation-based routines from the **mvtnorm** package, and they are only good to a few digits. If you re-run the commands, you'll get slightly different results.

All that said, the way the adjusted P values are printed is a result of the `print` method for `summary.ref.grid` objects. Such objects inherit from `data.frame`, so you can just extract the column you need. A technicality: the `lsmeans` call you show actually produces a `list` of two `ref.grid`s, so you need to pick out just the `$contrasts` member. Here's how it goes:

```
lsm <- lsmeans(fit, pairwise ~ type + age,
               at = list(age=c("40", "50", "60")), adjust = "mvt")
pval <- summary(lsm$contrasts)$p.value
```

Then format and print `pval` however you like. You can extract other results in a similar way.

But again, some thought was put into the way the P values are presented, and I think presenting them with exaggerated precision is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

First, is it really of *practical* importance to report a *p*-value to that level of precision?

Second, I believe this is probably due to your machine's precision ability. Before you run `options(scipen=100000000000)`, were you getting a *p*-value of 2.2e-16? This is what it is for most machines I've worked on. This is because the computer cannot go to more precise estimate than 16 digits.

To see what your computer is capable of, check out the documentation `?.Machine` and what the `.Machine` function returns.

For floats/doubles (i.e., numeric non-integers), you can enter `.Machine$double.eps` to see how precise your machine can get. For instance, see what happens when run this code:

```
> .Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16

> 1 + 2.22e-15 == 1
[1] FALSE

> 1 + 2.22e-17 == 1
[1] TRUE
```

My machine couldn't tell 1.000000000000000222 was different from 1.

See relevant discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970705/why-cant-i-get-a-p-value-smaller-than-2-2e-16).

Comment: There's an earlier, more extensive discussion on our own site [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78839/how-should-tiny-p-values-be-reported-and-why-does-r-put-a-minimum-on-2-22e-1/78840#78840)

Comment: @Glen_b nice and comprehensive!